# Group by two fields and filter by another field value get final result in each group

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an object structure like

```
public class Employee {
       private String name;
       privte String department;
       private String gender;
       private String designation;
       private Integer salary;         
}

 List<Employee> listEmployees = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
            new Employee("Mark", "Marketing", "male", "Sales Manager", 9200),
            new Employee("Tom", "Marketing", "male", "Sales Manager", 2800),
            new Employee("Travis", "Marketing", "male", "Sales Manager", 3850),
            new Employee("Diana", "Marketing", "female", "Sales Manager", 1900),
            new Employee("Keith", "R&D", "male", "Software Engineer", 4000),
            new Employee("Liam", "R&D", "male", "Software Engineer", 5200),
            new Employee("Whitney", "R&D", "female", "Software Engineer", 6000),
            new Employee("Tina", "R&D", "female", "Software Engineer", 7500)
            new Employee("Patrick", "Government", "female", "Service", 7100),
            new Employee("Luc", "Government", "male", "Service", 3300),
            new Employee("Philippe", "Government", "female", "Service", 2800),
            new Employee("David", "Government", "female", "Service", 4700)
    ));
```

I want result from this employee list from each department and gender who is earning highest salary.

I tried with two filed group by department and gender after that get result map inside map then list but how to filter by highest salary and get the final result from each group?

So my result would be like below.

```
Employee("Mark", "Marketing", "male", "Sales Manager", 9200)
Employee("Diana", "Marketing", "female", "Sales Manager", 1900)
Employee("Liam", "R&D", "male", "Software Engineer", 5200)
Employee("Tina", "R&D", "female", "Software Engineer", 7500)
Employee("Patrick", "Government", "female", "Service", 7100)
Employee("Luc", "Government", "male", "Service", 3300)
```

I have tried with below code:

```
employeeList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getGender)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using groupingBy would work but is overly complex and somewhat cumbersome to get the desired results. Assuming you had the getters defined, you could put them in a map where the `key` is the concatenation of the `departement and gender` and the `value` is the `Employee` instance.  Then use a `BinaryOperator` as a `mergeFunction` to replace the existing employee if the next employee's salary is higher.  The `LinkedHashMap` option is not required but is used to preserve the encounter order of the Employees.  To finish, the `values()` of the map are returned and put in a `List` and printed.

I am using a `record` for the demo.

```
record Employee(String getName, String getDepartment, String getGender,
        String getDesignation, Integer getSalary) {
     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return "Employee(%s, %s, %s, %s, %d)".formatted( getName, getDepartment, getGender,
                 getDesignation,getSalary);
     }
}
```

- function to select two fields.

```
Function<Employee, String> key = emp->emp.getDepartment()+emp.getGender();
```

- mergeFunction for desired return.

```
BinaryOperator<Employee> mergeFunction = (max, next) -> 
            max.getSalary() > next.getSalary() ? max : next;
```

The process

```
List<Employee> maxSalaries = new ArrayList<>(listEmployees.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                  emp->key.apply(emp), emp -> emp,
                 mergeFunction,
                 LinkedHashMap::new)).values());

maxSalaries.forEach(System.out::println);
```

New list of Employee:

```
Employee(Mark, Marketing, male, Sales Manager, 9200)
Employee(Diana, Marketing, female, Sales Manager, 1900)
Employee(Liam, R&D, male, Software Engineer, 5200)
Employee(Tina, R&D, female, Software Engineer, 7500)
Employee(Patrick, Government, female, Service, 7100)
Employee(Luc, Government, male, Service, 3300)
```

Here is a version that uses nested `groupingBy` collectors and a `reducing` collector.   I still prefer the first method but this may be more in line with what you want.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Employee>> results2 = listEmployees.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,
         Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getGender,
                 Collectors.reducing(new Employee("","","","",-1), mergeFunction ))));
 
 results2.forEach((k,v) -> {
     v.values().forEach(System.out::println);
     
 });
```

prints

```
Employee(Tina, R&D, female, Software Engineer, 7500)
Employee(Liam, R&D, male, Software Engineer, 5200)
Employee(Patrick, Government, female, Service, 7100)
Employee(Luc, Government, male, Service, 3300)
Employee(Diana, Marketing, female, Sales Manager, 1900)
Employee(Mark, Marketing, male, Sales Manager, 9200)
```

Comment: It is not possible to use multi field group by as I just made a snippet of code from my actual code. In the actual code I want to filter by some string instead of highest salary? I need new list of Employee.

Comment: Your question specified salary and that is what I showed.  The results are exactly what you said the expected output should be.  When you ask a question, please be specific, otherwise folks will be wasting their time.  You can always change the `mergeFunction`.

Comment: @RishiKumar I fixed it so you could specify the two fields in a `Function`.  And I put the results in a `List.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group by multiple fields you can create a record that encapsulates that grouping:

```
record DepartmentGender(String department, String gender) {
  DepartmentGender(Employee employee) {
    this(employee.getDepartment(), employee.getGender());
  }
}
```

If record is unavailable you can implement your own custom class (or you could use a third-party library such as [Tuple](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/package-summary.html) from Apache):

```
class DepartmentGender {
  String department;
  String gender;

  DepartmentGender(Employee employee) {
    department = employee.getDepartment();
    gender = employee.getGender();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s (%s)", department, gender);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
      return true;
    if (!(o instanceof DepartmentGender))
      return false;
    DepartmentGender other = (DepartmentGender)o;
    return (other.department.equals(department)) && (other.gender.equals(gender));
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return department.hashCode() * gender.hashCode();
  }
}
```

Then you can use this record as the key for you group (note that this does return an Optional<>):

```
listEmployees.stream()
  .collect(
    groupingBy(DepartmentGender::new,
               maxBy(comparingInt(Employee::getSalary)))
  )      
  .forEach((group, employee) -> System.out.println(group + " => " + employee.get()));
```

Giving the following output:

```
DepartmentGender[department=Marketing, gender=male] => Employee [Mark, Marketing, male, Sales Manager, 9200]
DepartmentGender[department=R&D, gender=male] => Employee [Liam, R&D, male, Software Engineer, 5200]
DepartmentGender[department=Marketing, gender=female] => Employee [Diana, Marketing, female, Sales Manager, 1900]
DepartmentGender[department=Government, gender=female] => Employee [Patrick, Government, female, Service, 7100]
DepartmentGender[department=Government, gender=male] => Employee [Luc, Government, male, Service, 3300]
DepartmentGender[department=R&D, gender=female] => Employee [Tina, R&D, female, Software Engineer, 7500]
```

Comment: Thanks David, Record I can not use in java 8, My current application in java 8 only

Comment: That's okay, you can create a custom class.  Record is just a convenience.